# C# Make a form a magnifying glass

Tags: c#, graphics, frameworks, zooming, transparent

How would I create a magnifying glass? I'm trying to make a windows form that appears as a magnifying glass when it is opened. Additionally it would be nice to rather sit in the middle of your screen (using Centerscreen). I want to make it so that users who struggle to see can enable a checkbox for the second form to appear (I have this part sorted) and specifically not using their mouse.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. The Q stands for "question". Have you considered asking one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400120/14171304

Comment: 1. you grab image below your form see [How can I access a graphics card's output directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549548/2521214) 2. you render magnified version of it somewhere

Comment: You know that [Windows already invented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-magnifier-to-make-things-on-the-screen-easier-to-see-414948ba-8b1c-d3bd-8615-0e5e32204198) this wheel, many years ago? Also, users with vision impairments will likely already be well set up with their own accessibility enhancements/software - providing your own is unlikely to be of benefit unless you know these users and they all have a specific complaint with every existing provision that you're trying to solve..